# How to publish a crate with optional dependency?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have some trouble about publishing crates with optional dependencies.

First, I execute `cargo publish`, but I don't see any optional dependencies compiled.

Then, I run `cargo publish --all-features`. The dependencies were compiled, but I don't see any modules with optional dependency in the documentation generated by `crates.io`.

What is the correct way to publish a crate with an optional dependency, which does not a default feature setting in `Cargo.toml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cargo publish` is the correct way to do it.

If you want that `docs.rs` (not `crates.io`) builds your documentation with some features enabled, use the `package.metadata.docs.rs` section in your `Cargo.toml`. I use the [Cargo.toml from the petgraph crate](https://docs.rs/crate/petgraph/0.6.0/source/Cargo.toml.orig) as an example (stripped):

```
[package]
name = "petgraph"
version = "0.6.0"
description = "Graph data structure library. Provides graph types and graph algorithms."
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
fixedbitset = { version = "0.4.0", default-features = false }
indexmap = { version = "1.6.2" }
quickcheck = { optional = true, version = "0.8", default-features = false }
serde = { version = "1.0", optional = true }
serde_derive = { version = "1.0", optional = true }

[...]

[features]
default = ["graphmap", "stable_graph", "matrix_graph"]
graphmap = []
stable_graph = []
matrix_graph = []
serde-1 = ["serde", "serde_derive"]

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
features = ["serde-1", "quickcheck"]
```